# get SESSION in a response function ( XMLHTML request ) in PHP

Tags: session

I try to throw $_SESSION["avalue"] from request.php file to response.php file like bellow:

request.php:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION["across"] = "across Session";
?>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function requestExample(){
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "../response.php?Name=Example", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

...

....... 
Response.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["Name"]))
{
    $name = $_GET["Name"];
    switch($name){
        case "Example":
            echo $_SESSION["across"];
            break;
                ......
    }
}

?>
```

I get error : Undefined index: across in .............../response.php

Comment: Perhaps you should create a session using `session_start()` at the top of your files.

Comment: Of course they have session_start() at the top! May javascript create a new difference session in Joomla? I had tried it in asp.net and it worked well. Thanks and wait for other reasons!

Comment: You realize that you also can't have any output before your call to `session_start`? You could also check you ajax request using something like `firebug`. You could also check around this site looking for someone that have asked something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by using code bellow. [Source http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_access_session_variables_set_by_an_external_script]

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );


require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();


$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$user = $session->get( 'across' );
```

Thanks!